# Sort a column in a primefaces datatable with a custom function

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable implemented with lazy loading and pagination. I have defined the next properties for this element:

```
<p:dataTable 
                             id="receiverList" 
                             var="receiver" 
                             widgetVar="receiverListVar"
                             value="#{receiverListBean.receiversModel}"  
                             filterDelay="750"
                             lazy="true" 
                             emptyMessage="#{text['list.empty']}" 
                             rows="20"
                             paginator="true"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} ({totalRecords})"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             style="text-align: center;margin:0;"   
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="15,20,25"
                             rowStyleClass="text-center #{(receiver.state eq 'CLOSED' or  receiver.state eq 'SIGNED' or receiver.state eq 'CANCELED')? 'tag-verde ' : 'tag-vermelha '}"
                             resizableColumns="true"
                             selection="#{receiverListBean.selectedMultipleReceivers}"  
                             filteredValue="#{receiverListBean.filteredReceivers}"
                             tableStyleClass="table table-condensed table-bordered"  
                             sortBy="#{receiver.expediteDate}"  
                             sortOrder="descending"
                             rowKey="#{receiver.id}"> 

 <p:column  
                  headerText="#{text['expedition.refExpedition']}" 
                  rendered="#{receiverListBean.viewColumn('refExpedition')}"
                  sortBy="#{receiver.expediteNumberDisplay}"
                  sortFunction="#{receiverListBean.mySort}" style="width:10%;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{not empty receiver.expediteNumberDisplay ? receiver.expediteNumberDisplay : '-'}"/>
</p:column> 

...
```

Bean

The bean responsible for this datatable has a function to make a custom sort of the column with the attribute expediteNumberDisplay. The expediteNumberDisplay is a String and I need to implement a sort method with numbers contained in this Object (like split the string by "\" and calculate the order, based on the result of that operation).

```
public int mySort(String s1, String s2) {

        Integer score = 0;
        Integer score2 = 0;

        String[] result = s1.split("/");
        if(result.length == 2)
            score = Integer.parseInt(result[0]) + Integer.parseInt(result[1]);

        String[] result2 = s2.split("/");
        if(result2.length == 2)
            score2 = Integer.parseInt(result2[0]) + Integer.parseInt(result2[1]);

        System.out.println("Entrei no score");

        return score2.compareTo(score);
    }
```

Model

```
public class Receiver
{
...
//format number/year
private String expediteNumberDisplay;
..
}
```

I try to put mySort(Object s1, Object s2), and cast the Objects but nothing happens. I made different approaches but the sort function was never reached Any Idea?

Comment: May be because you imply lazy = true. And where is your extension of LazyDataModel with method load? Sorting and filtering with  LazyDataModel must be inside method load. Good example on showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml. Write your own sorter class implements Comparator